# how to add super privileges to mysql database?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to execute query in mysql.

```
SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators =1;
```

> Error:
>
> SQL query:
> SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators =1
> MySQL said:
> #1227 - Access denied; you need the SUPER privilege for this operation

I want to know that how do i assign `SUPER` privileges to any database

Comment: Are you able to log in as the root user for this MySQL server?

Comment: yes but my database is from godaddy and starfield is third party handling it. so it does not show privileges.

Comment: Are you just one tenant amongst many in this DB server?
I doubt they will let you have the `SUPER` privilege to administer the whole server if that's the case.

Comment: Very recently in 2017, `SUPER` is [now deprecated](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_super).

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You can add super privilege using `phpmyadmin`:

> Go to PHPMYADMIN > privileges > Edit User > Under Administrator tab Click SUPER. > Go

If you want to do it through `Console`, do like this:

```
 mysql> GRANT SUPER ON *.* TO user@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

After executing above code, end it with:

```
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

You should do it with `*.*` (all databases) because SUPER is not a privilege which applies just to one database, it's global.

Comment: can you help me where to find privileges option

Comment: do i need  to execute this in query window? 
in your query what is *.* ?

Comment: I used the console (my phpmyadmin does't have a privileges tab) and both queries return OK, 0 rows affected. but then I still get the permission error when trying to create a trigger.

Comment: I tried this with a specific table (rather than `*.*`), but received the error `Incorrect usage of DB GRANT and GLOBAL PRIVILEGES`. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need apostrophes around username in your answer but other than that it is great

Comment: @onebree https://manidba.wordpress.com/2011/09/02/mysql-error-1221-hy000-incorrect-usage-of-db-grant-and-global-privileges/

Comment: Is there any other step involved as well, if mysql is on AWS RDS ?

Answer (score 9):

You can see the privileges here.[image]

Then you can edit the user

Comment: it is there in local host but my database is from godaddy and starfield is third party handling it. so it does not show privileges.

Comment: There is nothing like Privileges in my phpMyadmin.

Answer (score 3):

In Sequel Pro, access the User Accounts window. Note that any MySQL administration program could be substituted in place of Sequel Pro.

Add the following accounts and privileges:

`GRANT SUPER ON *.* TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD`

Answer (score 0):

just the query phpmyadmin prints after granting super user. hope help someone with console:

ON $.$ TO-> $=* doesnt show when you put two with a dot between them.

> REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* FROM 'usr'@'localhost';  GRANT ALL
>   PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'usr'@'localhost' REQUIRE NONE WITH GRANT OPTION
>   MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR
>   0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0;

and the reverse one, removing grant:

> REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* FROM 'dos007'@'localhost'; REVOKE GRANT
>   OPTION ON *.* FROM 'dos007'@'localhost'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.*
>   TO 'dos007'@'localhost' REQUIRE NONE WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0
>   MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS
>   0;

checked on vagrant should be working in any mysql

Answer (score 0):

On Centos 5 I was getting all sorts of errors trying to make changes to some variable values from the MySQL shell, after having logged in with the proper uid and pw (with root access).  The error that I was getting was something like this:

```
mysql> -- Set some variable value, for example
mysql> SET GLOBAL general_log='ON';
ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
```

In a moment of extreme serendipity I did the following:

```
OS-Shell> sudo mysql                          # no DB uid, no DB pw
```

**Kindly note that I did not provide the DB uid and password**

```
mysql> show variables;
mysql> -- edit the variable of interest to the desired value, for example
mysql> SET GLOBAL general_log='ON';
```

It worked like a charm