# how to solve access denied into my mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, cpanel

I don't know when I run the following code in phpMyAdmin

```
SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1;

    -- ----------------------------
    -- Function structure for `__mydiv`
    -- ----------------------------
    DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `__mydiv`;
    DELIMITER ;;
    CREATE   FUNCTION `__mydiv`(`a` int, `b` int) RETURNS bigint(20)
    BEGIN

            return FLOOR(a / b);
    END;;
    DELIMITER ;

    -- ----------------------------
    -- Function structure for `__mymod`
    -- ----------------------------
    DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `__mymod`;
    DELIMITER ;;
    CREATE   FUNCTION `__mymod`(`a` int, `b` int) RETURNS bigint(20)
    BEGIN

            return (a - b * FLOOR(a / b));
    END;;
    DELIMITER ;

    -- ----------------------------
    -- Function structure for `_gdmarray`
    -- ----------------------------
    DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `_gdmarray`;
    DELIMITER ;;
    CREATE   FUNCTION `_gdmarray`(`m` smallint) RETURNS smallint(2)
    BEGIN

            CASE m
                    WHEN 0 THEN RETURN 31;
                    WHEN 1 THEN RETURN 28;
                    WHEN 2 THEN RETURN 31;
                    WHEN 3 THEN RETURN 30;
                    WHEN 4 THEN RETURN 31;
                    WHEN 5 THEN RETURN 30;
                    WHEN 6 THEN RETURN 31;
                    WHEN 7 THEN RETURN 31;
                    WHEN 8 THEN RETURN 30;
                    WHEN 9 THEN RETURN 31;
                    WHEN 10 THEN RETURN 30;
                    WHEN 11 THEN RETURN 31;
            END CASE;

    END;;
    DELIMITER ;

    -- ----------------------------
    -- Function structure for `_jdmarray`
    -- ----------------------------
    DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `_jdmarray`;
    DELIMITER ;;
    CREATE   FUNCTION `_jdmarray`(`m` smallint) RETURNS smallint(2)
    BEGIN

            CASE m
                    WHEN 0 THEN RETURN 31;
                    WHEN 1 THEN RETURN 31;
                    WHEN 2 THEN RETURN 31;
                    WHEN 3 THEN RETURN 31;
                    WHEN 4 THEN RETURN 31;
                    WHEN 5 THEN RETURN 31;
                    WHEN 6 THEN RETURN 30;
                    WHEN 7 THEN RETURN 30;
                    WHEN 8 THEN RETURN 30;
                    WHEN 9 THEN RETURN 30;
                    WHEN 10 THEN RETURN 30;
                    WHEN 11 THEN RETURN 29;
            END CASE;

    END;;
    DELIMITER ;

    -- ----------------------------
    -- Function structure for `_jdmarray2`
    -- ----------------------------
    DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `_jdmarray2`;
    DELIMITER ;;
    CREATE   FUNCTION `_jdmarray2`(`m` smallint) RETURNS smallint(2)
    BEGIN


            CASE m
                    WHEN 1 THEN RETURN 31;
                    WHEN 2 THEN RETURN 31;
                    WHEN 3 THEN RETURN 31;
                    WHEN 4 THEN RETURN 31;
                    WHEN 5 THEN RETURN 31;
                    WHEN 6 THEN RETURN 31;
                    WHEN 7 THEN RETURN 30;
                    WHEN 8 THEN RETURN 30;
                    WHEN 9 THEN RETURN 30;
                    WHEN 10 THEN RETURN 30;
                    WHEN 11 THEN RETURN 30;
                    WHEN 12 THEN RETURN 29;
            END CASE;

    END;;
    DELIMITER ;

    -- ----------------------------
    -- Function structure for `pdate`
    -- ----------------------------
    DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `pdate`;
    DELIMITER ;;
    CREATE   FUNCTION `pdate`(`gdate` datetime) RETURNS char(100) CHARSET utf8
    BEGIN


            DECLARE 
                    i,
                    gy, gm, gd,
                    g_day_no, j_day_no, j_np,
                    jy, jm, jd INT DEFAULT 0; /* Can be unsigned int? */
            DECLARE resout char(100);
            DECLARE ttime CHAR(20);

            SET gy = YEAR(gdate) - 1600;
            SET gm = MONTH(gdate) - 1;
            SET gd = DAY(gdate) - 1;
            SET ttime = TIME(gdate);
            SET g_day_no = ((365 * gy) + __mydiv(gy + 3, 4) - __mydiv(gy + 99, 100) + __mydiv (gy + 399, 400));
            SET i = 0;

            WHILE (i < gm) do
                    SET g_day_no = g_day_no + _gdmarray(i);
                    SET i = i + 1; 
            END WHILE;

            IF gm > 1 and ((gy % 4 = 0 and gy % 100 <> 0)) or gy % 400 = 0 THEN 
                    SET g_day_no =  g_day_no + 1;
            END IF;

            SET g_day_no = g_day_no + gd; 
            SET j_day_no = g_day_no - 79;
            SET j_np = j_day_no DIV 12053;
            SET j_day_no = j_day_no % 12053;
            SET jy = 979 + 33 * j_np + 4 * __mydiv(j_day_no, 1461);
            SET j_day_no = j_day_no % 1461;

            IF j_day_no >= 366 then 
                    SET jy = jy + __mydiv(j_day_no - 1, 365);
                    SET j_day_no = (j_day_no - 1) % 365;
            END IF;

            SET i = 0;

            WHILE (i < 11 and j_day_no >= _jdmarray(i)) do
                    SET j_day_no = j_day_no - _jdmarray(i);
                    SET i = i + 1;
            END WHILE;

            SET jm = i + 1;
            SET jd = j_day_no + 1;
            SET resout = CONCAT_WS ('-', jy, jm, jd);

            IF (ttime <> '00:00:00') then
                    SET resout = CONCAT_WS(' ', resout, ttime);
            END IF;

            RETURN resout;
    END;;
    DELIMITER ;

    -- ----------------------------
    -- Function structure for `PMONTH`
    -- ----------------------------
    DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `PMONTH`;
    DELIMITER ;;
    CREATE   FUNCTION `PMONTH`(`gdate` datetime) RETURNS char(100) CHARSET utf8
    BEGIN


            DECLARE 
                    i,
                    gy, gm, gd,
                    g_day_no, j_day_no, j_np,
                    jy, jm, jd INT DEFAULT 0; /* Can be unsigned int? */
            DECLARE resout char(100);
            DECLARE ttime CHAR(20);

            SET gy = YEAR(gdate) - 1600;
            SET gm = MONTH(gdate) - 1;
            SET gd = DAY(gdate) - 1;
            SET ttime = TIME(gdate);
            SET g_day_no = ((365 * gy) + __mydiv(gy + 3, 4) - __mydiv(gy + 99, 100) + __mydiv(gy + 399, 400));
            SET i = 0;

            WHILE (i < gm) do
                    SET g_day_no = g_day_no + _gdmarray(i);
                    SET i = i + 1; 
            END WHILE;

            IF gm > 1 and ((gy % 4 = 0 and gy % 100 <> 0)) or gy % 400 = 0 THEN 
                    SET g_day_no = g_day_no + 1;
            END IF;

            SET g_day_no = g_day_no + gd;
            SET j_day_no = g_day_no - 79;
            SET j_np = j_day_no DIV 12053;
            set j_day_no = j_day_no % 12053;
            SET jy = 979 + 33 * j_np + 4 * __mydiv(j_day_no, 1461);
            SET j_day_no = j_day_no % 1461;

            IF j_day_no >= 366 then 
                    SET jy = jy + __mydiv(j_day_no - 1, 365);
                    SET j_day_no =(j_day_no - 1) % 365;
            END IF;

            SET i = 0;

            WHILE (i < 11 and j_day_no >= _jdmarray(i)) do
                    SET j_day_no = j_day_no - _jdmarray(i);
                    SET i = i + 1;
            END WHILE;

            SET jm = i + 1;
            SET jd = j_day_no + 1;
            RETURN jm;
    END;;
    DELIMITER ;

    -- ----------------------------
    -- Function structure for `pmonthname`
    -- ----------------------------
    DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `pmonthname`;
    DELIMITER ;;
    CREATE   FUNCTION `pmonthname`(`gdate` datetime) RETURNS varchar(100) CHARSET utf8
    BEGIN

            CASE PMONTH(gdate)
                    WHEN 1 THEN RETURN 'ÝÑæÑÏíä';
                    WHEN 2 THEN RETURN 'ÇÑÏíÈåÔÊ';
                    WHEN 3 THEN RETURN 'ÎÑÏÇÏ';
                    WHEN 4 THEN RETURN 'ÊíÑ';
                    WHEN 5 THEN RETURN 'ãÑÏÇÏ';
                    WHEN 6 THEN RETURN 'ÔåÑíæÑ';
                    WHEN 7 THEN RETURN 'ãåÑ';
                    WHEN 8 THEN RETURN 'ÂÈÇä';
                    WHEN 9 THEN RETURN 'ÂÐÑ';
                    WHEN 10 THEN RETURN 'Ïí';
                    WHEN 11 THEN RETURN 'Èåãä';
                    WHEN 12 THEN RETURN 'ÇÓÝäÏ';
            END CASE;

    END;;
    DELIMITER ;

    -- ----------------------------
    -- Function structure for `pyear`
    -- ----------------------------
    DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `pyear`;
    DELIMITER ;;
    CREATE   FUNCTION `pyear`(`gdate` datetime) RETURNS char(100) CHARSET utf8
    BEGIN

            DECLARE
                    i,
                    gy, gm, gd,
                    g_day_no, j_day_no, j_np,
                    jy, jm, jd INT DEFAULT 0; /* Can be unsigned int? */
            DECLARE resout char(100);
            DECLARE ttime CHAR(20);

            SET gy = YEAR(gdate) - 1600;
            SET gm = MONTH(gdate) - 1;
            SET gd = DAY(gdate) - 1;
            SET ttime = TIME(gdate);
            SET g_day_no = ((365 * gy) + __mydiv(gy + 3, 4) - __mydiv(gy + 99, 100) + __mydiv(gy + 399, 400));
            SET i = 0;

            WHILE (i < gm) do
                    SET g_day_no = g_day_no + _gdmarray(i);
                    SET i = i + 1;
            END WHILE;

            IF gm > 1 and ((gy % 4 = 0 and gy % 100 <> 0)) or gy % 400 = 0 THEN
                    SET g_day_no =  g_day_no + 1;
            END IF;

            SET g_day_no = g_day_no + gd;
            SET j_day_no = g_day_no - 79;
            SET j_np = j_day_no DIV 12053;
            set j_day_no = j_day_no % 12053;
            SET jy = 979 + 33 * j_np + 4 * __mydiv(j_day_no, 1461);
            SET j_day_no = j_day_no % 1461;

            IF j_day_no >= 366 then
                    SET jy = jy + __mydiv(j_day_no - 1, 365);
                    SET j_day_no = (j_day_no - 1) % 365;
            END IF;

            SET i = 0;

            WHILE (i < 11 and j_day_no >= _jdmarray(i)) do
                    SET j_day_no = j_day_no - _jdmarray(i);
                    SET i = i + 1;
            END WHILE;

            SET jm = i + 1;
            SET jd = j_day_no + 1;
            RETURN jy;
    END;;
    DELIMITER ;

    -- ----------------------------
    -- Function structure for `pday`
    -- ----------------------------
    DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `pday`;
    DELIMITER ;;
    CREATE   FUNCTION `pday`(`gdate` datetime) RETURNS char(100) CHARSET utf8
    BEGIN


            DECLARE
                    i,
                    gy, gm, gd,
                    g_day_no, j_day_no, j_np,
                    jy, jm, jd INT DEFAULT 0; /* Can be unsigned int? */
            DECLARE resout char(100);
            DECLARE ttime CHAR(20);

            SET gy = YEAR(gdate) - 1600;
            SET gm = MONTH(gdate) - 1;
            SET gd = DAY(gdate) - 1;
            SET ttime = TIME(gdate);
            SET g_day_no = ((365 * gy) + __mydiv(gy + 3, 4) - __mydiv(gy + 99 , 100) + __mydiv(gy + 399, 400));
            SET i = 0;

            WHILE (i < gm) do
                    SET g_day_no = g_day_no + _gdmarray(i);
                    SET i = i + 1;
            END WHILE;

            IF gm > 1 and ((gy % 4 = 0 and gy % 100 <> 0)) or gy % 400 = 0 THEN
                    SET g_day_no = g_day_no + 1;
            END IF;

            SET g_day_no = g_day_no + gd;
            SET j_day_no = g_day_no - 79;
            SET j_np = j_day_no DIV 12053;
            SET j_day_no = j_day_no % 12053;
            SET jy = 979 + 33 * j_np + 4 * __mydiv(j_day_no, 1461);
            SET j_day_no = j_day_no % 1461;

            IF j_day_no >= 366 then
                    SET jy = jy + __mydiv(j_day_no - 1, 365);
                    SET j_day_no = (j_day_no-1) % 365;
            END IF;

            SET i = 0;

            WHILE (i < 11 and j_day_no >= _jdmarray(i)) do
                    SET j_day_no = j_day_no - _jdmarray(i);
                    SET i = i + 1;
            END WHILE;

            SET jm = i + 1;
            SET jd = j_day_no + 1;
            RETURN jd;
    END;;
    DELIMITER ;


    -- ----------------------------
    -- Function structure for `_gdmarray2`
    -- ----------------------------
    DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `_gdmarray2`;
    DELIMITER ;;
    CREATE   FUNCTION `_gdmarray2`(`m` smallint, `k` SMALLINT) RETURNS smallint(2)
    BEGIN


            CASE m
                    WHEN 0 THEN RETURN 31;
                    WHEN 1 THEN RETURN 28+k;
                    WHEN 2 THEN RETURN 31;
                    WHEN 3 THEN RETURN 30;
                    WHEN 4 THEN RETURN 31;
                    WHEN 5 THEN RETURN 30;
                    WHEN 6 THEN RETURN 31;
                    WHEN 7 THEN RETURN 31;
                    WHEN 8 THEN RETURN 30;
                    WHEN 9 THEN RETURN 31;
                    WHEN 10 THEN RETURN 30;
                    WHEN 11 THEN RETURN 31;
            END CASE;


    END;;
    DELIMITER ;

    -- ----------------------------
    -- Function structure for `gdate`
    -- ----------------------------
    DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `gdate`;
    DELIMITER ;;
    CREATE   FUNCTION `gdate`(`jy` smallint, `jm` smallint, `jd` smallint) RETURNS datetime
    BEGIN

            DECLARE
                    i, j, e, k, mo,
                    gy, gm, gd,
                    g_day_no, j_day_no, bkab, jmm, mday, g_day_mo, bkab1, j1
            INT DEFAULT 0; /* Can be unsigned int? */
            DECLARE resout char(100);
            DECLARE fdate datetime;


      SET bkab = __mymod(jy,33);

      IF (bkab = 1 or bkab= 5 or bkab = 9 or bkab = 13 or bkab = 17 or bkab = 22 or bkab = 26 or bkab = 30) THEN
        SET j=1;
      end IF;

      SET bkab1 = __mymod(jy+1,33);

      IF (bkab1 = 1 or bkab1= 5 or bkab1 = 9 or bkab1 = 13 or bkab1 = 17 or bkab1 = 22 or bkab1 = 26 or bkab1 = 30) THEN
        SET j1=1;
      end IF;

            CASE jm
                    WHEN 1 THEN IF jd > _jdmarray2(jm) or jd <= 0 THEN SET e=1; end IF;
                    WHEN 2 THEN IF jd > _jdmarray2(jm) or jd <= 0 THEN SET e=1; end IF;
                    WHEN 3 THEN IF jd > _jdmarray2(jm) or jd <= 0 THEN SET e=1; end IF;
                    WHEN 4 THEN IF jd > _jdmarray2(jm) or jd <= 0 THEN SET e=1; end IF;
                    WHEN 5 THEN IF jd > _jdmarray2(jm) or jd <= 0 THEN SET e=1; end IF;
                    WHEN 6 THEN IF jd > _jdmarray2(jm) or jd <= 0 THEN SET e=1; end IF;
                    WHEN 7 THEN IF jd > _jdmarray2(jm) or jd <= 0 THEN SET e=1; end IF;
                    WHEN 8 THEN IF jd > _jdmarray2(jm) or jd <= 0 THEN SET e=1; end IF;
                    WHEN 9 THEN IF jd > _jdmarray2(jm) or jd <= 0 THEN SET e=1; end IF;
                    WHEN 10 THEN IF jd > _jdmarray2(jm) or jd <= 0 THEN SET e=1; end IF;
                    WHEN 11 THEN IF jd > _jdmarray2(jm) or jd <= 0 THEN SET e=1; end IF;
                    WHEN 12 THEN IF jd > _jdmarray2(jm)+j or jd <= 0 THEN SET e=1; end IF;
            END CASE;
      IF jm > 12 or jm <= 0 THEN SET e=1; end IF;
      IF jy <= 0 THEN SET e=1; end IF;

      IF e>0 THEN
        RETURN 0;
      end IF;

      IF (jm>=11) or (jm=10 and jd>=11 and j=0) or (jm=10 and jd>11 and j=1) THEN
        SET i=1;
      end IF;
      SET gy = jy + 621 + i;

      IF (__mymod(gy,4)=0) THEN
        SET k=1;
      end IF;

            IF (__mymod(gy,100)=0) and (__mymod(gy,400)<>0) THEN
                    SET k=0;
            END IF;

      SET jmm=jm-1;

      WHILE (jmm > 0) do
        SET mday=mday+_jdmarray2(jmm);
        SET jmm=jmm-1;
      end WHILE;

      SET j_day_no=(jy-1)*365+(__mydiv(jy,4))+mday+jd;
      SET g_day_no=j_day_no+226899;


      SET g_day_no=g_day_no-(__mydiv(gy-1,4));
      SET g_day_mo=__mymod(g_day_no,365);

            IF (k=1 and j=1) THEN
                    IF (g_day_mo=0) THEN
                            RETURN CONCAT_WS('-',gy,'12','30');
                    END IF;
                    IF (g_day_mo=1) THEN
                            RETURN CONCAT_WS('-',gy,'12','31');
                    END IF;
            END IF;

            IF (g_day_mo=0) THEN
                    RETURN CONCAT_WS('-',gy,'12','31');
            END IF;


      SET mo=0;
      SET gm=gm+1;
      while g_day_mo>_gdmarray2(mo,k) do
                    SET g_day_mo=g_day_mo-_gdmarray2(mo,k);
        SET mo=mo+1;
        SET gm=gm+1;
      end WHILE;
      SET gd=g_day_mo;

      RETURN CONCAT_WS('-',gy,gm,gd);
    END;;
    DELIMITER ;

    -- ----------------------------
    -- Function structure for `gdatestr`
    -- ----------------------------
    DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `gdatestr`;
    DELIMITER ;;
    CREATE   FUNCTION `gdatestr`(`jdat` char(10)) RETURNS datetime
    BEGIN

            DECLARE
                    i, j, e, k, mo,
                    gy, gm, gd,
                    g_day_no, j_day_no, bkab, jmm, mday, g_day_mo, jd, jy, jm,bkab1,j1
            INT DEFAULT 0; /* ### Can't be unsigned int! ### */
            DECLARE resout char(100);
            DECLARE jdd, jyd, jmd, jt varchar(100);
            DECLARE fdate datetime;

            SET jdd = SUBSTRING_INDEX(jdat, '/', -1);
            SET jt = SUBSTRING_INDEX(jdat, '/', 2);
            SET jyd = SUBSTRING_INDEX(jt, '/', 1);
            SET jmd = SUBSTRING_INDEX(jt, '/', -1);
            SET jd = CAST(jdd as SIGNED);
            SET jy = CAST(jyd as SIGNED);
            SET jm = CAST(jmd as SIGNED);


             SET bkab = __mymod(jy,33);

      IF (bkab = 1 or bkab= 5 or bkab = 9 or bkab = 13 or bkab = 17 or bkab = 22 or bkab = 26 or bkab = 30) THEN
        SET j=1;
      end IF;

      SET bkab1 = __mymod(jy+1,33);

      IF (bkab1 = 1 or bkab1= 5 or bkab1 = 9 or bkab1 = 13 or bkab1 = 17 or bkab1 = 22 or bkab1 = 26 or bkab1 = 30) THEN
        SET j1=1;
      end IF;

            CASE jm
                    WHEN 1 THEN IF jd > _jdmarray2(jm) or jd <= 0 THEN SET e=1; end IF;
                    WHEN 2 THEN IF jd > _jdmarray2(jm) or jd <= 0 THEN SET e=1; end IF;
                    WHEN 3 THEN IF jd > _jdmarray2(jm) or jd <= 0 THEN SET e=1; end IF;
                    WHEN 4 THEN IF jd > _jdmarray2(jm) or jd <= 0 THEN SET e=1; end IF;
                    WHEN 5 THEN IF jd > _jdmarray2(jm) or jd <= 0 THEN SET e=1; end IF;
                    WHEN 6 THEN IF jd > _jdmarray2(jm) or jd <= 0 THEN SET e=1; end IF;
                    WHEN 7 THEN IF jd > _jdmarray2(jm) or jd <= 0 THEN SET e=1; end IF;
                    WHEN 8 THEN IF jd > _jdmarray2(jm) or jd <= 0 THEN SET e=1; end IF;
                    WHEN 9 THEN IF jd > _jdmarray2(jm) or jd <= 0 THEN SET e=1; end IF;
                    WHEN 10 THEN IF jd > _jdmarray2(jm) or jd <= 0 THEN SET e=1; end IF;
                    WHEN 11 THEN IF jd > _jdmarray2(jm) or jd <= 0 THEN SET e=1; end IF;
                    WHEN 12 THEN IF jd > _jdmarray2(jm)+j or jd <= 0 THEN SET e=1; end IF;
            END CASE;
      IF jm > 12 or jm <= 0 THEN SET e=1; end IF;
      IF jy <= 0 THEN SET e=1; end IF;

      IF e>0 THEN
        RETURN 0;
      end IF;

      IF (jm>=11) or (jm=10 and jd>=11 and j=0) or (jm=10 and jd>11 and j=1) THEN
        SET i=1;
      end IF;
      SET gy = jy + 621 + i;

      IF (__mymod(gy,4)=0) THEN
        SET k=1;
      end IF;

            IF (__mymod(gy,100)=0) and (__mymod(gy,400)<>0) THEN
                    SET k=0;
            END IF;

      SET jmm=jm-1;

      WHILE (jmm > 0) do
        SET mday=mday+_jdmarray2(jmm);
        SET jmm=jmm-1;
      end WHILE;

      SET j_day_no=(jy-1)*365+(__mydiv(jy,4))+mday+jd;
      SET g_day_no=j_day_no+226899;


      SET g_day_no=g_day_no-(__mydiv(gy-1,4));
      SET g_day_mo=__mymod(g_day_no,365);

            IF (k=1 and j=1) THEN
                    IF (g_day_mo=0) THEN
                            RETURN CONCAT_WS('-',gy,'12','30');
                    END IF;
                    IF (g_day_mo=1) THEN
                            RETURN CONCAT_WS('-',gy,'12','31');
                    END IF;
            END IF;

            IF (g_day_mo=0) THEN
                    RETURN CONCAT_WS('-',gy,'12','31');
            END IF;


      SET mo=0;
      SET gm=gm+1;
      while g_day_mo>_gdmarray2(mo,k) do
                    SET g_day_mo=g_day_mo-_gdmarray2(mo,k);
        SET mo=mo+1;
        SET gm=gm+1;
      end WHILE;
      SET gd=g_day_mo;

      RETURN CONCAT_WS('-',gy,gm,gd);
    END;;
    DELIMITER ;
```

Then I receive the error:

```
#1227 - Access denied; you need the SUPER privilege for this operation
```

I've changed all database command such as select delete alter, ... to yes into my MySQL database manager. I am using directAdmin v1.41.1.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to add super privileges to mysql database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11946012/how-to-add-super-privileges-to-mysql-database)

Answer (score 0):

I would try to GRANT permissions to that user ID and client IP and see if that helps.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html

Comment: i've changed grant permissions to yes into my database manager too.