# Turn MySQL event scheduler ON - AWS EC2 instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm attempting to create scheduled events in MySQL, but running up against this error in MySQL.

```
Error

SQL query:

SET GLOBAL event_scheduler =  "ON"

MySQL said:

#1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) 
for this operation
```

I have both root and ec2-user access to the EC2 server (which is running MySQL). I can SSH in, or connect using MySQL workbench, but can't figure out how (or which user) to give SUPER privileges from within AWS.

I have no "Privileges" tab on phpmyadmin. I also can't seem to get any kind of MySQL command-line access when I SSH in. Not sure how to get there...

Comment: This thread explains ways to setup super user privileges:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11946012/how-to-add-super-privileges-to-mysql-database

Comment: So maybe the question then should be: I can't seem to get command line access to mysql when I SSH into the EC2 server. Not a big command line expert. And PHPMyAdmin doesn't have the privileges tab.

Comment: Depending on what sort Linux distro you are running, the root mysql user will have a given default password (empty in MANY cases so you can try that first if you don't want to determine your distro's settings).