# PHP error need (at least one of) the SHOW DATABASES privilege(s)

Tags: php

I am having an error after i've uploaded my website saying

Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SHOW DATABASES privilege(s) for this operation

I have searched with the same matter on google and i have found some saying my.ini is needed to be configured

But i dont know where that my.ini file is even located. Will that solve my problem if configured properly? Where can i find it?

Any advice will surely be appreciated

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First of all i would recommend you to use `GRANTS`

SO first run the  command `SHOW GRANTS;` which  displays  the privileges granted explicitly to the named account.

Try loggin in with root permission

`mysql -uroot`

If you cant login with the root permission..

Make some changes to the `ini` file

`[mysqld]
skip-grant-tables
skip-networking`

and do a restart.

Comment: It'll be very bad to skip the grant tables. You should set the correct permissions and better use `mysql -uroot -p`. Then you could grant the right privileges in mysql via `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'user'@'localhost';`

Comment: i'm sorry sir but i'm really not getting you. how am i albe to loggin with root permission? may you please be more specific? and as i have said on my post that i even dont know the location/directory of that ini file i reall am sorry sir really noob with that matter thanks

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11946012/how-to-add-super-privileges-to-mysql-database..accept the ans if it helps .thanx