# MySQL Workbench Import failure -- You do not have the SUPER privilege

Tags: mysql, heroku

I have setup MySQL Workbench and linked to ClearDB in heroku. Upon attempting to import a schema, the error appears:

```
ERROR 1419 (HY000) at line 582: You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)

Operation failed with exitcode 1
```

How can I add SUPER user privilege?

Comment: You might find this SO question useful: ["*how to add super privileges to mysql database?*"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11946012/1364007).

Comment: What command that requires `SUPER` is on line 582?