# SQL trigger won't execute

Tags: sql, triggers, heidisql

The following trigger won't execute in HeidiSQL or phymyadmin, any assistance would be gretly appreciated in fixing.

I'm using heidisql, and they used workbench. though this shouldn't matter

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER t_l_in_a 
   BEFORE UPDATE ON x_l
   FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   IF OLD.in_a = 1 THEN
       SET NEW.status = 0;
   END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER;
```

Assuming table names and col names are correct.

Thanks much.

ps. This is the error:
**SQL Error (1419): You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)**

I am using an Admin user for the DB,

Comment: Have you checked the privileges?  this is apparently a new feature since MySQL 5.06.  You may need to set it to  be able to use `ALTER PROCEDURE`.  Are you using phpMyadmin?

Comment: Hi I am using HeidiSQL

Comment: okay can you run command line?

Comment: Try this:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/11946043/3044080

Comment: Yes, also it is on an Amazon EWS server

Comment: try that link;  it looks like it should work

Comment: Thanks, I found the solution here:
https://techtavern.wordpress.com/2013/06/17/mysql-triggers-and-amazon-rds/

Answer (score 0):

As we are using Amazon EWS this answered the question:
https://techtavern.wordpress.com/2013/06/17/mysql-triggers-and-amazon-rds/