# #1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SHOW DATABASES privilege(s) for this operation

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am following the new boston mysql tutorials, and at the very beginning he is writing **`SHOW DATABASES`**. In my case I get the following error

> "#1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SHOW DATABASES privilege(s) for this operation".

I am very new to **phpmyadmin** and I have googled how to grant a permission but I am unlucky

Answer (score 1):

You need to have that privilege granted to the user ie

```
GRANT SHOW DATABASES ON *.* TO $username_here
```

The docs for this can be found here

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html

Someone here also had a similar problem with PHPMYADMIN.

[how to add super privileges to mysql database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11946012/how-to-add-super-privileges-to-mysql-database)

Depending on your username you can also use this from the console

```
GRANT SUPER ON *.* TO user@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password_asljk8902314';
flush privileges;
```

Please make sure your username is correct.

Comment: I tried many different times and I still get errors like this:

Comment: Do you have root access to the machine?

Comment: im doing it on hostinger. Its online

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this is the syntax I was using to import the database:

```
mysql -u jaimemontoya -pMyPasswordHere -h [name_here].ondigitalocean.com -P [port_number_here] -D cloned_db < cloned_db.sql
```

This was the error:

```
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 18: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER, SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN or SESSION_VARIABLES_ADMIN privilege(s) for this operation
```

The root cause of the problem was that in my `cloned_db.sql` file, I had the following lines:

```
SET @MYSQLDUMP_TEMP_LOG_BIN = @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN;
SET @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN= 0;
SET @@GLOBAL.GTID_PURGED=/*!80000 '+'*/ 'aef25hke-65h7-35jk-s54k-4567g3f6437e:3-69538';
SET @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN = @MYSQLDUMP_TEMP_LOG_BIN;
```

I commented out those lines and executed again `mysql -u jaimemontoya -pMyPasswordHere -h [name_here].ondigitalocean.com -P [port_number_here] -D cloned_db < cloned_db.sql`. The database was imported successfully.