# getting error when run query

Tags: php, mysql

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `vw_all_users_password`  AS  select `d003_portalusers`.`id` AS `id`,999999 AS `mobile`,`d003_portalusers`.`user_id` AS `email`,`d003_portalusers`.`password` AS `password`,1 AS `user_type` from `d003_portalusers` union select `d003_users`.`id` AS `id`,`d003_users`.`mobile` AS `mobile`,`d003_users`.`user_email` AS `email`,`d003_users`.`user_password` AS `password`,2 AS `user_type` from `d003_users` where (`d003_users`.`user_type` = 'vendor') union select `d003_users`.`id` AS `id`,`d003_users`.`mobile` AS `mobile`,`d003_users`.`user_email` AS `email`,`d003_users`.`user_password` AS `password`,3 AS `user_type` from `d003_users` where (`d003_users`.`user_type` <> 'vendor') ;
```

in my localhost view is created and i want to create same view in live server.
I got this error when I run this query-

> 1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

Comment: You need the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11946012/how-to-add-super-privileges-to-mysql-database