# Warning: Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=767311

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have an issue here. I know this topic is not new to this forum. I am asking this question again because I was stuck somewhere while implementing the solutions.

It's a wordpress site.

First, I receive the below error:

> Warning: Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=767311 in
>   /home/trapexco/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1877 Warning:
>   Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output
>   started at /home/trapexco/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php:1877) in
>   /home/trapexco/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1179

On a client's website after he gave someone the admin login to install a plugin without my consent.

The above error only shows at the homepage, while every other page shows well.

I have disabled the said plugin and even disabled all other plugins but all to no avail.

In MySQL Query Browser I ran the below query:

```
show variables like 'max_allowed_packet' which gave me 268435456
```

But when I execute the query:

```
set global max_allowed_packet=524288000
```

I got:

> 1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation.

Answer (score 1):

You need super privilege to perform this action.

```
mysql> GRANT SUPER ON *.* TO user@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

After executing above code, end it with:

```
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

See original answer: [how to add super privileges to mysql database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11946012/how-to-add-super-privileges-to-mysql-database)