# How to add 'Super' privileges to the Aurora database?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

Although a variation of this question has been asked before it did not help. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11946012/how-to-add-super-privileges-to-mysql-database) for anyone interested.

`mysql> GRANT SUPER ON *.* TO root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`

I ran the above command but I receive the following error, even though I am the root user:

> Access denied for user 'root'@'%' (using password: YES)

I have also create a custom *Parameter Group* and set the `log_bin_trust_function_creators=1` and rebooted the instance, but still I don't have *Super Privileges*. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot grant SUPER on an Aurora (or any RDS) database.

Some things that require SUPER can be set via the parameter group settings, and there are some built-in stored procedures for some other common task.

Comment: thanks, that would make would make sense as one of the reasons I wanted need SUPER was to turn on "event_scheduler". But I found that you can just turn that on in parameters.