# you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) in mysql (Live Server)

Tags: mysql, database, events, scheduler

I am trying to create an event in the live server but i am getting this problem when setting the global event_scheduler on. Can anyone help to solve this problem??

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add super privilege using phpmyadmin:

```
Go to PHPMYADMIN > privileges > Edit User > Under Administrator tab Click SUPER. > Go
```

If you want to do it through Console, do like this:

```
 mysql> GRANT SUPER ON *.* TO user@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

After executing above code, end it with:

```
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

You should do in on . because SUPER is not the privilege that applies just to one database, it's global.

You Can Read More Information [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11946012/how-to-add-super-privileges-to-mysql-database/11946043)

Comment: Phpmyadmin is not showing the privileges section. And For granting via console i think i have to be the super user by default which i am not.

Comment: AS a user who doesn't have admin access can't add privileges. This would defeat the whole purpose of authentication/authorisation.

You can reset the root password following the step outlined in this http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/recover-mysql-root-password.html.

For More inforation, Visit this link
https://serverfault.com/questions/264170/adding-a-mysql-user-when-no-mysql-users-have-admin-rights