# #1227 - Access denied; you need the SUPER privilege for this operation - how to solve?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to change a SQL Variable through phpMyAdmin, and I get this error:

> #1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

[image: Access denied]

Trying to solve this error has led me to [this question here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11946012/how-to-add-super-privileges-to-mysql-database).  Unfortunately all of the proposed solutions do not seem to work for me:

> Go to PHPMYADMIN > privileges > Edit User > Under Administrator tab Click SUPER. > Go

As you can see from the screenshot above, there is no "privileges" tab in my phpMyAdmin.

> mysql> GRANT SUPER ON *.* TO user@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

When I try to execute code like this, I get further errors:

> Access denied for user 'cpses_ajceej5cb1'@'localhost'

I have never heard of this `cpses...` user before, they certainly don't seem to exist anywhere.  Here is a screenshot of the issue:

[image: Access denied again]

Given all of these set backs, how can I change a variable in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: That looks like it's the user that phpMyAdmin is using, so possibly isn't suspicious. Can you connect to MySQL directly, i.e. through the command line client or MySQL Workbench (or just something other than phpMyAdmin), and log in as the instance's root user?

Comment: @Rup phpMyAdmin is the only access I have to MySQL, so I cannot connect directly unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the only way I could edit these variables wasn't through phpMyAdmin at all - I had to alter them through cPanel.

Comment: How exactly did you alter the values on the cPanel? I'm having this error too.