# ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation - on AWS Lightsail Mysql DB

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I restored an AWS Lightsail DB (HA) from an emergency restore - and now I can't create functions or drop triggers, etc, when logged in as dbmasteruser - I receive this message:

> Error Code: 1419. You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary
>   logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe
>   log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)

I've tried the console statement:  `SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1;` but get the access denied message.

Has anybody seen this before and know how to fix it? Much obliged.

Comment: Have you considered granting the super privilege to dbmasteruser: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11946012/how-to-add-super-privileges-to-mysql-database